# 75 records of data in app. Parse CSV, make XML, or use SQLite?

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, csv

Trying to make my first Android app.  Excited to be asking my first question here!   I'm no longer a young dog, so any encouragement is much appreciated.

I am rewriting a simple data driven webpage I wrote in the past.  The data is currently stored in a SQL database (populated from a CSV)   I select the data, apply some logic as I iterate the records, and basically create an HTML table.  Let's just say the table displays some information about various cars.

My question is relating to the KISS approach to storing this data.  There are only 75 records in the table.  I just select them all, and iterate through the fetch array.

For the app, should I just parse the CSV using some kind of FileStreamReader and parsing classes, and populate some sort of collection of Car objects?

Should I translate this data into an XML and parse the XML?

Worth trying to use SQLite?  Or best to avoid?  (I really don’t like over-engineered approaches to anything)

Comment: You will receive the data from the internet or the app will already have the data ?

Comment: Already have the data

Comment: I may be wrong, but i think read from a file is slower than read on Database, if this data will not change, you can put they in the String resources as a Array, if you will change and store the data, i recommend SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up converting my flat file into an XML file.  I don't see any advantage this offered except for complicating my code.  I should have just parsed the flat file and created an array of objects directly from the flat file records.

In hindsight, SQL was clearly overkill for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend create a database on SQLite. It offers some advantages for example the data types, because it only has 4 types. The control of the data is easy.
XML generates files which can overload the device depending how much they are